# Show that the product of two transpositions can be expressed as a product of $3$-cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Consider the symmetric group $S_n$ where $n>2.$

Show that the product of two transpositions $(ab),\,(cd)$ can be written as a product of $3$-cycles where $a,b,c,d$ are all distinct.

I'm not sure where a sensible place to start is so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: A good way to start is to try something. After a short to medium time, you will find two $3$-cycles that work.

Comment: Thank you. I was just wondering if there was any systematic way of doing it instead of just trying different $3$-cycles.

Comment: For more general problems of this nature, it would be worthwhile to develop some machinery. But the main purpose of this exercise is to give you practice in multiplying permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $(ab)(cd) = (ab)(bc)(bc)(cd)= (abc)(bcd)$.

Answer (score 0):

$(abc)$ maps $a$ to $b$, $b$ to $c$, and $c$ to $a$. Now, all we need to do is map $c$ to $a$ (so $b \mapsto c \mapsto a$), $a$ to $d$ ($c \mapsto a \mapsto d$), and $d$ to $c$ — i.e., $(cad)$. Thus, $(ab)(cd) = (cad)(abc)$.